# Grouping related functions in Python

Tags: python

Suppose I have a module with functions `spam` and `ham` which use functions `eggs` and `foo`.

```
def spam():
    eggs()
    foo()
    ...

def ham():
    eggs()
    foo()
    ...
```

Now, `eggs` and `foo` are only used by `spam` and `ham`, and so it doesn't make sense to expose them at the module level. I could change their names to `_eggs` and `_foo` to indicate that they are for internal use but this doesn't really establish the relation between `spam`, `ham`, `eggs` and `foo`.

So, I could make a container class to hold these functions like this:

```
class SpamHam:

    @staticmethod
    def _eggs():
        ...

    @staticmethod
    def _foo():
        ...

    @staticmethod
    def spam():
        ...        

    @staticmethod
    def ham():
        ...
```

But this seems skethy because I expect users not to instantiate `SpamHam` and only use it to call the static methods. Plus it doesn't really seem right to use a class when all I want is to establish some relation between its methods.

I could create a separate module called `spamham` and put these four functions into that, but `spam` and `ham` really do 'belong' to the module they are already in.

So, what is correct way to establish such relations in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, I would advise to not think of these things as specific relations between functions.  A function *should be* a self-contained unit of code<sup>1</sup>.  My central thesis here is that you shouldn't think of `eggs` as belonging to `spam` and `ham`.  `eggs` shouldn't care if it gets called by `spam` or `ham` or `bacon` or `toast`.  The important thing is that `eggs` has a name that as clearly as possible gives you an immediate idea what the function *does*<sup>2</sup>.

The trick is to figure out which functions you want people on the outside to have access to ... That determines whether it's `eggs` (Public) or `_eggs` (Implementation detail that could change without notice) as you've already alluded to.

<sup><sup>1</sup>This isn't to say that functions can't call other functions</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup>Preferably the *correct* idea about what the function does... :)</sup>

Comment: Also consider using `__all__` on your module.

Comment: @kindall -- Sure.  There's no harm in that.  I suppose it gives another layer of "By the way, this is a public name".  But personally, I've never found a whole lot of use for `__all__`.  People who `from blah import *` deserve whatever bad things happen to their code from it ;-)

Comment: `help(modulename)` respects `__all__` so it's very useful, in my opinion.